# KingswaySoft SSIS error when Published - A password is required

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dynamics-crm, kingswaysoft

I've created a package that gets some information from a sql database and inserts them into Dynamics CRM.

When testing the package from Visual Studio everything goes as expected and the task finishes without any errors and the rows get inserte . However , when I publish the package to SSISDB on Sql Server the package fails with this error :

> KingswaySoft.IntegrationToolkit.DynamicsCrm.CrmServiceException : CRM service call returned an error : A password is required in order to establish the connection ...

I tried changing the package protection level to EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey but it still gives the same message as above , created the package again from scratch still doesn't work . This package was working before , maybe there's something I did the last time in configuration which made it work but I cannot replicate it anymore .

Also I tried the Integrated Authentication it says this :

> KingswaySoft.IntegrationToolkit.DynamicsCrm.CrmServiceException : CRM service call returned an error : The caller was not authenticated by the service .

Comment: When running locally your using your credentials, when running from the job it is using the server credentials.  Check those.

Comment: yes but the thing is that the error is stating that the password is missing not that the credentials are wrong . And , the credentials i'm providing have privileges in sql server .

Comment: When you publish the package there are options for security when uploading.  Something like rely on server, use pw, and a few others.  Maybe upload again and confirm what one you are using when uploading the package

Answer (score 1):

@Drinv, this is a typical SSIS runtime deployment issue. You need to make sure that you have provided a password for your job configuration for the connection manager. What you provided to the package doesn't count as far as sensitive fields are concerned (password being one) when you are using the EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey option since user key is not transferrable between different systems or different users. An easy workaround is to change your SSIS package/project's ProtectionLevel setting to encrypt using a password instead, although it may not be the best practice. If you still have trouble getting this going, please reach out to us directly, our team can walk you through the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation , but I found the answer to be easier than expected . Below is the answer .

Answer (score 1):

I found out what I was doing wrong .

My SSIS project was on Project Deployment Model and I was trying to deploy only the package. After making my connections available on project level and deploying the whole project everything worked as expected .